# What's another way to say "it's been said time and time again"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

I often find myself at a shortage of words to properly describe my thoughts. Usually, I just use the "Define" function on Google. However, Google can't provide synonyms for  for idioms/sayings such as this.

Anyway, I'm looking for another way to say "it's been said time and time again".

Comment: Requests for online resources are on topic at [meta]. But please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  Phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. [(more¹)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [(more²)](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) [(more³)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3226/14073)

Answer (score 2):

**[ad-nauseam](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ad%20nauseam)**

> My weekend will consist of **hearing ad nauseam** what a perfect life my older sister, Monica, has with her perfect husband, perfect children and perfect house

The Latin expression *ad nauseam* means "to the point of nausea", where one (perhaps metaphorically) feels physically sick from hearing it over and over again.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is a very nice first answer. :) If you stick around have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out what ELU is all about.

Answer (score 1):

You may use
***[reiterate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reiterate):***

> - to repeat something you have already said in order to emphasize it

..."it has been reiterated...."